# Cloud Spanner complex primary key and queries

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I'm playing with Cloud Spanner and I created an imgur clone with the schema as follows:

`CREATE TABLE Images (id STRING(36) NOT NULL, createdAt TIMESTAMP, caption STRING(1024), fileType STRING(10)) PRIMARY KEY (id, createdAt DESC)`

The id is a version 4 UUID as the GCP documentation specifies so that I avoid hotspots. The createdAt is a timestamp when an image is first created. I have my PRIMARY KEY defined as (id, createdAt DESC) so that I can more easily query by latest added images.

What I don't understand is what happens if I want to get a single image using only `SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id = 'some UUID`? Will Spanner still search by key in an efficient way, meaning getting the information from the server that stores the specific key in its key range even though I only specified a part of the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

In your simple example, yes. It will try to come up with an efficient execution plan which may include using an index (automatically created for PKs) even though your predicate is on just 1 of the 2-column composite PK because it is on the 1 column. If your predicate was just "...createdAt= then it will scan the table. It would be far more expensive to find matches for col2 in your composite PK of (col1, col2) than it is to just scan col2.

This assumes there's enough data to matter. For example, if you have 42 rows, it really won't matter how you execute the query or what predicates were provided; the number off I/O requests (often the most expensive part of a query) will be the same.

In general, Spanner tries to pick the index it thinks will be most efficient. The actual physical steps don't work like that but conceptually, it's a reasonable way to think about it.

Whether an index is helpful or not depends on a few things and whether it gets picked or not also has dependencies. Does it have statistics, are the statistics correct/fresh, is it making correct estimates on row counts, etc... Composite indexes/keys are a just a bit more interesting as noted above.

Just make sure you always test with enough data (closely matching your production environment if possible).